# In the real Device(LG Optimus Me) can't get the registration ID from C2DM Server?

Tags: android-c2dm

I am unable to get the registration ID from `C2DM` Server.
I got the reply as `Authentication Failed Error`.

In the `sender ID` I only pass my gmail account id.

Note: In the Mobile phone i was logged in via gmail account id.

Can anyone help me to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify whether your Market was in Sync on device with same gmail ID.